# Local Mosquitto broker bridging to a remote broker (AWS IoT Core - a thing)

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, mosquitto, bridge

I am attempting to bridge a local Mosquitto broker to a remote broker (AWS IoT Core) using the MQTT communication protocol. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS via WSL on Windows 10 Pro x64. for setup and configuration, I followed the tutorial "How to Bridge Mosquitto MQTT Broker to AWS IoT" per the link below:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-bridge-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-aws-iot/

When I attempt to send a pub request to the MQTT Client test on the AWS IoT, I get a "protocol error" response. I am very new to both MQTT and Mosquitto configuration and implementation. I have attached my Mosquitto.log, bridge.conf, mosquitto.conf, and the AWS IoT policy files for your review. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Moquitto.log

1667834604: Client local.bridgeaws disconnected: Protocol error. 
1667834635: Bridge local.bridgeaws doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic   test/testing                                       
1667834635: Connecting bridge (step 1) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)
1667834640: Connecting bridge (step 2) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)        
1667834640: Bridge bridgeaws sending CONNECT                                                                         
1667834661: Client local.bridgeaws disconnected: Protocol error.                                                     
1667834692: Bridge local.bridgeaws doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic test/testing                                       
1667834692: Connecting bridge (step 1) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)        
1667834692: Connecting bridge (step 2) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)        
1667834692: Bridge bridgeaws sending CONNECT                                                                         
1667834713: Client local.bridgeaws disconnected: Protocol error.                                                     
1667834744: Bridge local.bridgeaws doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic test/testing                                       
1667834744: Connecting bridge (step 1) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)        
1667834744: Connecting bridge (step 2) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)        
1667834744: Bridge bridgeaws sending CONNECT                                                                         
1667834765: Client local.bridgeaws disconnected: Protocol error.                                                     
1667834774: Bridge local.bridgeaws doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic test/testing                                       
1667834774: Connecting bridge (step 1) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)        
1667834774: Connecting bridge (step 2) bridge_to_remote (xxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883)        
1667834774: Bridge bridgeaws sending CONNECT                                                                         
1667834795: Client local.bridgeaws disconnected: Protocol error.
```

```
# Bridge Configuration - bridge.conf

allow_anonymous true
connection bridge_to_remote
address xxxxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883

# Topics for Pub and Sub                                                                                               
topic test/testing both 0

# Setting protocol version explicitly                                                                                  
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_insecure false   

# Configuration Settings                                                                                               
clientid bridgeaws
cleansession true
start_type automatic
try_private false
notifications false
log_type all
use_identity_as_username true

# Path to the certifications                                                                                           
bridge_cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/Amazon-root-CA-1.pem 
bridge_certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/device.pem.crt
bridge_keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/private.pem.key
```

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at                                                                   
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

```
My AWS IoT Policy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried relocating the bridge.conf file directly into the mosquitto.conf file, but that did not rectify the problem. Additionally, when  I ran the Mosquitto_pub with the strace option, I get the output below.

```
futex(0x7f7de5bde920, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f7de5bdeb80, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0                                                   
futex(0x7f7de5bdeb7c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0                                                   
futex(0x7f7de5bde70c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0                                                   
futex(0x7f7de5bdeb8c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0                                                   
futex(0x7f7de5c937c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
sysinfo({uptime=11577, loads=[33984, 37856, 38400], totalram=17085169664, freeram=13048745984, sharedram=0, bufferram=0, totalswap=31925248000, freeswap=31925248000, procs=7, totalhigh=142548992, freehigh=278528, mem_unit=1}) = 0                 
futex(0x7f7de5c937d4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f7de5c937d0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0                                                   
futex(0x7f7de5c937c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0                                                   
brk(0x7fffca51b000)                     = 0x7fffca51b000                                                    
brk(0x7fffca53c000)                     = 0x7fffca53c000                                                    
brk(0x7fffca561000)                     = 0x7fffca561000                                                    
brk(0x7fffca582000)                     = 0x7fffca582000                                                    
brk(0x7fffca581000)                     = 0x7fffca581000                                                    
brk(0x7fffca5a9000)                     = 0x7fffca5a9000                                                    
futex(0x7f7de5bdef20, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0                                                   
getpid()                                = 521
getrandom("\x18\xf4\x8c\xb7\x1d\x1e\x80\xfe\x9e\xfb\x64\x53\xd0\x19\x25\x24\x71\x81\x6d\xb4\xea\xee\x95\x74\x07\x53\xff\xf5\x8e\xc8\x9e\x63"..., 48, 0) = 48
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                                              openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
etsockopt(5, SOL_TCP, TCP_ULP, [7564404], 4) = -1 ENOPROTOOPT (Protocol not available)                     
newfstatat(1, "", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x4, 0x1), ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0                
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0         
write(1, "Client bridgeaws sending CONNECT"..., 33Client bridgeaws sending CONNECT) = 33
write(4, "\0", 1)                       = 1
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)
getpid()                                = 521
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500)                             
getpid()                                = 521                                                               
time(NULL)                              = 1667838905 (2022-11-07T11:35:05-0500) 
close(5)                                = 0
write(5, "\26\3\1\1W\1\0\1S\3\3\320\334\324\360-\366(\356\3647\344@\4\2426\362E\245\2001O"..., 348) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)  close(5)                                = 0                                                                 
write(2, "Error: Protocol error\n", 22Error: Protocol error ) = 22                                                            exit_group(1)                           = ?                                                                 
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Can you share your `bridge.conf`file? Also, the output trace is empty.

Comment: I've fixed most of the code bocks, but what ever you copied/pasted from added LOT of useless spaces and stripped all the carriage returns. You will need to fix the strace output, because I really don't have the patience...

Comment: Please removed the iot endpoint.

Comment: I edited and removed the iot endpoint. Apologies for a messy post. Also, I added my bridge.conf file.

Comment: @km2022, please make sure you have created a thing in IoT Core named: bridgeaws. Also, make sure the certificate is attached to the thing and the policy is attached to the cert.

Comment: @AnthonyB. I double checked that the policy is attached to the cert and the cert is attached to my thing. The problem still persists.

Comment: Can you check that you can ping the aws iot core endpoint on port 8883 from your wsl?

Comment: @Anthony B. I am unable to ping  my IoT endpoint at neither port 8883 nor 443 from my WSL.

Comment: well, this is a problem. Open the port from your laptop.